# Table view cell Optional - swift

Tags: swift, option-type

I have researched this question to no end but continue to struggle.  I have seen the following code written as :  cell.textLabel?.text when creating cells.  Why is there a question mark only on textLabel and not text?

According to apple docs, textLabel is an optional property of type UILabel and text is an optional string, yet we only use one question mark?  Why not two questions marks, one for each optional?

Comment: What language is this for? Swift?

Comment: Yes swift language

Comment: `textLabel?.text` means it checks for if `textLabel` is `nil` or not. If it is `nil`, don't proceed further to `.text` and if its not `nil`, then proceed to `.text`. This applies everywhere

Answer (score 1):

The `textLabel` of `UITableViewCell` is optional because the label can be missing when using a **custom** cell.

If you are using the standard cell with one of the 4 predefined styles `textLabel` is guaranteed to exist and you can safely unwrap the optional: `cell.textLabel!.text`

To answer the question the first question mark is required for [Optional Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html), any optional except the last item in a chain (`foo.bar.baz`) must be marked as optional or unwrapped. In case of the last item the compiler can "negotiate" a type match directly with the item across the equal sign.